# Which best way to run verticle in vert.x?

Tags: java, vert.x

I am new to Vertex.

I have main verticle for accepting HTTP request and four other verticles.

Advice me please best way to run verticle.

first

```
vertx run com.xxx.MainVerticle -cluster
vertx run com.xxx.OtherVericle2 -cluster
vertx run com.xxx.OtherVericle3 -cluster
vertx run com.xxx.OtherVericle4 -cluster
vertx run com.xxx.OtherVericle5 -cluster
```

second

```
command vertx run com.xxx.MainVerticle and
vertx.deployVerticle("OtherVericle1") in MainVerticle.
vertx.deployVerticle("OtherVericle2") in MainVerticle.
vertx.deployVerticle("OtherVericle3") in MainVerticle.
vertx.deployVerticle("OtherVericle4") in MainVerticle.
```

Which best way to run verticle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form will create five JVM processes with clustered Vert.x instances.

The second form will create just one JVM process with non clustered Vert.x instance.

It's difficult to answer your question without further details but usually you want clustered Vert.x if you need [High Availability and Fail-Over](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_high_availability_and_fail_over)

Comment: thank you. i run two servers. currently, each of server consists of first method.